# What would the Valar do if they knew Saruman had joined Sauron?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

As we wall know Saruman was a Maiar and Istari, and was a student of Manwë, and is known to be wise if not wiser than the rest of the Maiar Posse, my question is what would the Valar do to Saruman if they found out about his betrayal of them?

Comment: In real life if you know you have a traitor, but the traitor doesn't know you know, you can use them to send disinformation to the enemy.

Comment: I don't think this has a good answer not based on opinion. I don't think it's the sort of question this site is designed for.

Comment: They would send him Gandalf the white ;-)

Comment: The Valar had a hands-off strategy in Middle Earth since the last two interventions destroyed Beleriland and Numenor, and made the earth round.  If they felt the cure was worse than the disease for Sauron's threat, Saruman would not change the decision.

Comment: @JoeL. Even if the traitor knows that you know, if you *know* that they know and they *don't* know that *you* know that they know, you can do the same. But if they know that you know that they know that you know... then things start to get confusing...

Answer (score 6):

### "To him"? Nothing<sup>1</sup>

This is never explicitly stated in the text, but I say this for two reasons:

1. **The Istari seem to have been given a high degree of autonomy in how they pursued their mission.** In the essay *The Istari*, Tolkien writes (bold is my emphasis, italix is his):

   > Now these Maiar were sent by the Valar at a crucial moment in the history of Middle-earth to enhance the resistance of the Elves of the West, greatly outnumbered by those of the East and South. **It may be seen that they were free each to do what they could in this mission**; that they were not commanded or supposed to act *together* as a small central body of power and wisdom
   >
   > <sup><sub>*Unfinished Tales:* Part 4 II: "The Istari"</sub></sup>
2. **It seems unlikely that Manwë *didn't* know.** It seems clear from *The Silmarillion* that Manwë sees nearly everything that happens on Middle Earth; this is suggested a few times, but I'll only quote the most direct:

   > Manwë Súlimo, highest and holiest of the Valar, sat upon the borders of Aman, forsaking not in his thought the Outer Lands. For his throne was set in majesty upon the pinnacle of Taniquetil, the highest of the mountains of the world, standing upon the margin of the sea. Spirits in the shape of hawks and eagles flew ever to and from his halls; and their eyes could see to the depths of the seas, and pierce the hidden caverns beneath the world. Thus they brought word to him of well nigh all that passed in Arda; yet some things were hidden even from the eyes of Manwë and the servants of Manwë, for where Melkor sat in his dark thought impenetrable shadows lay.
   >
   > <sup><sub>*The Silmarillion* Quenta Silmarillion Chapter 1: "Of the Beginning of Days"</sub></sup>

   There doesn't seem to be much that could obscure Manwë's sight; the designs of Morgoth could do it, but there aren't very many of those in the Third Age. Considering that the Valar knew enough to send the Istari in the first place, I imagine they're keeping a close eye on them.

   And yet, Saruman isn't struck down for failing his mission. If the Valar were going to do something, presumably they would have.

### But

I said the Valar would do nothing, which is an oversimplification. They actually did something: they banished him from Aman. This is made very clear from Saruman's death scene in *Return of the King*:

> [S]uddenly Wormtongue rose up, drawing a hidden knife, and then with a snarl like a dog he sprang on Saruman’s back, jerked his head back, cut his throat, and with a yell ran off down the lane. Before Frodo could recover or speak a word, three hobbit-bows twanged and Wormtongue fell dead.
>
> To the dismay of those that stood by, about the body of Saruman a grey mist gathered, and rising slowly to a great height like smoke from a fire, as a pale shrouded figure it loomed over the Hill. For a moment it wavered, looking to the West; but out of the West came a cold wind, and it bent away, and with a sigh dissolved into nothing.
>
> <sup><sub>*Return of the King* Book 6 Chapter 8: "The Scouring of the Shire"</sub></sup>

So the Valar did something to him after all: they settled his fate, which is the same as the one Sauron set for himself.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is an oversimplification, as the latter half of my answer makes clear; for the record, I'm not considering Gandalf's renewed authority to be something they do "to" Saruman. For one thing, that was Eru's decision rather than that of the Valar. For another, I think the OP is wondering about actual punishment, and I see the point of elevating Gandalf to be a last-ditch attempt to salvage the purpose of the Istari, rather than punishing those who had strayed. YMMV.

As [Matt Gutting points out in comments](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/86488/what-would-the-valar-do-if-they-knew-saruman-had-joined-sauron/86500?noredirect=1#comment189370_86500), Gandalf doesn't see himself as responsible for punishing Saruman:

> [']What will you do to [Saruman]?' asked Pippin.
>
> 'I? Nothing!' said Gandalf. 'I will do nothing to him. I do not wish for mastery. What will become of him? I cannot say.[']
>
> <sup><sub>*The Two Towers* Book 3 Chapter 10: "The Voice of Saruman"</sub></sup>

Comment: And don't forget Gandalf's own comment: "'And what if Sauron does not conquer? What will you do to him?' asked Pippin. 'I? Nothing!' said Gandalf. 'I will do nothing to him. I do not wish for mastery.'"

Comment: @MattGutting That is indeed a good point, thanks! I've added it in